# trying username and password on a portal

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
import urllib.error
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

userlist = tuple(range(161320,161345))
passlist = ('qq')

for username in userlist:
    for password in passlist:
        url='URL'
        encoded=requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('username', 'password'))
    #data = { 'username': username, 'password': password }
    encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')
        #encoded = json.dumps(data)
        request = urllib.request.Request(url,encoded)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        payload = response.read().decode()

        if "You have successfully logged in"  in payload: 
            print(f"{user} {password}")
```

its not working showing a number of error mention below:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PYHTON/NEW SCRPT.py", line 4, in 
    from requests import HTTPDigestAuth
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPDigestAuth'

Comment: Reconsider to switch to [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

Comment: new to this thing didn't get it. can you explain in detail

Comment: [install](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#install) then follow the pattern in [basic-authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

Comment: showing this : data=requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'password'))
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

Comment: Have your installed the `requests` package? Please [edit] your Question and add your `import` line.

Comment: i have edited the import check

Comment: `PYHTON` looks dubious

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! With respect to the error you're getting, `urllib` doesn't expect POST data to be a normal string - it needs to be encoded as a byte array. You can fix this by just encoding the data before sending it:

```
encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')
```

Note that this is different from `urlencode`. That just replaces particular characters in a string with special codes, but the result is still a normal string.

As @stovfl suggested, though, making web requests in Python is *much* easier with the very popular [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. Follow the installation instructions (these vary depending on how you installed Python, but you probably just need to type `pip install requests` in a command prompt), then go to the [basic authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) example and adapt it for your use case.

Comment: showing this error                                                           T raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PYHTON/NEW SCRPT.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests import HTTPDigestAuth
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPDigestAuth'

Comment: Looks like it should be `from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth` instead of `from requests import HTTPDigestAuth`.

Comment: can you please edit this line too - encoded=requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('username', 'password'))

Comment: `username` and `password` should be the username and password you're trying to authenticate with. I appreciate that you are trying to get to the bottom of this, but please remember that StackOverflow is a question and answer site, not a forum or tutorial site. If there's something specific about the Requests library that's not working, then please make a new question. It's not a great idea to edit your existing question as your work on a solution, since now my answer appears to be completely unrelated to your question.